# What happens when I change int 8 to int 16

Tags: matlab

I understand that the int value is in relation with the storage capacity.But, if I change int 8 to int 16 only the capacity will be altered?

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answers have not yet formalized this I will give you and explanation including some keywords to look up and some more elaborate explanation.

The size of a data type is actually based on the capacity of the storage.

> int8 - 8 bits signed integer, MSB (most significant bit) representing the sign. Range [-2^7,2^7-1] = [-128,127]
>
> uint8 - 8 bits unsigned integer, MSB denotes the highest power of 2. Range [0,2^8-1] = [0,255]
>
> int16 - 16 bits signed integer
>
> uint16 - 16 bits unsigned integer

I could keep going but you probably get the picture. There is also **int32, uint32, int64, uint64.**

There is also **char** which can be used for text, but also instead of **uint8** (in MATLAB a **char** is 16-bits though) (with the difference that char is printed as a char and not a number). This is normal to do for many c-like languages.

The types **float** and **double** is different since they use a floating point precision, standardized by the IEEE. The format is used to represent large numbers in a good way.

This data type uses an exponential representation of the numbers. The data type allocates a fixed set of bits for exponential and precision digits and one bit for sign. A floating point number can be divided like this,

> (sign),Mantissa,exponent

For double the bit allocation is 1-bit for sign, 11-bits for exponent, 52-bits for Mantissa. For single it is 8-bits for exponent, 23-bits for Mantissa.

This is some necessary background for discussing type conversion. When discussing type conversion you normally speak about **implicit conversion** and **explicit conversion**. The terms is not really relevant for Matlab since Matlab can identify type automatically.

```
a = 2; % a is a double
b=a; % b is a double

c = int8(57); % c is an int8
d = c; % d is an int 8
```

However explicit conversion is done with the built in conversion functions.

```
c = int8(57);
d = char(c);
```

When discussing different kinds of conversion we often talk about **type promotion** and **type demotion**. Type promotion is when a data type of lower precision is *promoted* to a type of higher precision.

```
a = int8(57);
b = int16(a);
```

This is lossless and considered safe. Type demotion is on the other hand when a type of higher precsion is converted to a type of lower precision.

```
c = int16(1234);
d = int8(c); % Unsafe! Data loss
```

This is generally considered risky and shuold be avoided. Normally the word type demotion is not used so often since this conversion is uncommon. A conversion from higher to lower precision needs to be checked.

```
function b = int16ToInt8(a)
if (any(a < -128 | a > 127))
    error('Variable is out of range, conversion cannot be done.');
end
b=int8(a);
```

In most languages type demotion cannot be done implicitly. Also conversion between floating point types and integer types should be avoided.

An important note here is how Matlab initiates variables. If a "constructor" is **not** used (like `a=int8(57)`), then Matlab will automatically set the variable to double precision. Also, when you initiate a vector/matrix of integers like `int64([257,3745,67])`, then the "constructor" for the matrix is called first. So `int64()` will actually be called on a matrix of doubles. This is important because if the integer needs more precsion than 52-bits, the precision is too low for a double. So

```
int64([2^53+2^0,2^54+2^1, 2^59+2^2]) ~=
         [int64(2^53) + int64(2^0), int64(2^54)+ int64(2^1), int64(2^59)+ int64(2^2)]
```

Further, in case the memory on the device allows it is commonly recommended to use **int32** or **int64** and **double**

Answer (score 1):

Each type of integer has a different range of storage capacity:

int 8: Values range from -128 to 127

int 16: Values range from -32,768 to 32,767

Answer (score 1):

You only need to worry about data loss when converting to a *lower precision* datatype. Because `int16` is higher precision than `int8`, your existing data will remain intact but your data can span twice the range of values at the cost of taking up twice as much space (2 bytes vs. 1 byte)

```
a = int8(127);
b = int16(a);

a == b
% 1

whos('a', 'b')

%  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
%
%  a         1x1                 1  int8
%  b         1x1                 2  int16
```

Answer (score 1):

`int8` variables can range from -128 to 127, while this range for `int16` class is from -32,768 to 32,767. Obviously, memory is the price to pay for the wider range ;)

**Note 1:** *These limits do not apply only on the variables when defining them, but also usually on the outputs of calculations!*

Example:

```
>> A = int8([0, 10, 20, 30]);
>> A .^ 2

ans =

  0  100  127  127

>> int16(A) .^ 2

ans =

  0  100  400  900
```

**Note 2:** *Once you switch to* `int16`, *usually you should do it for all variables that participate in calculations together.*

Example:

```
>> A + int16(A)
Error using  + 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.
```